# Unity VR UI Не корректная работает On Click

Tags: unity3d, ui, click, vr

Делаю приложение на Unity для VR, разрабатываю меню, поставил панель с кнопками, запихнул в On Click скрипт с функцией обработчиком, но кнопка прожимается с рандомной попытки. Можно и раз 100 нажать, собственно вопрос как сделать так чтобы нажатие сразу срабатывало? Само нажатие кнопки на контроллере регистрируется (отследил через дебаг), а по кнопке меню реагирует рандомно.

Comment: UI кнопка работает если нажать и отжать в пределах кнопки? Вот что в доках написано `Note: Triggered on MouseUp after MouseDown on the same object.` . Попробуй просто через `MouseDown` вызывать обработчик

Comment: на Button стоит On Click и я не вижу возможности его поменять, он там по умолчанию, плюс обработчик MouseDown для мыши, а у меня VR приложение, это немного другое